# AJAX POST model empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am having a problem passing a model with an Ajax post request.

Values are passed into the Javascript function below, the variables are converted into a JSON string and sent to the controller method.

When using the Dev Tools in Chrome I can see that the data is being sent as expected.

The problem is that the properties of the object parameter in the controller are all 0. Why is this happening and how can it be fixed?

**Example Data**

EventID = 419656

EventStart = Tue Dec 05 2017 10:00:00 GMT+0000

EventEnd = Tue Dec 05 2017 11:00:00 GMT+0000

**JavaScript**:

```
function UpdateEvent(EventID, EventStart, EventEnd) {

    alert(EventID);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/Calendar/UpdateEvent",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            Id: EventID,
            NewEventStart: EventStart,
            NewEventEnd: EventEnd
        })
    });
}
```

**Model**:

```
public class UpdateAppt
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime NewEventStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime NewEventEnd { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**:

```
[RoutePrefix("Calendar"), Route("{action=index}")]
public class CalendarController : Controller
{

    public void UpdateEvent(UpdateAppt updateModel )
    {
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you need to `.stringify` the `data` given you are setting `contentType: "application/json"`?

Comment: Give example of data being sent. The question in its current state is unclear as it is incomplete and would require too many questions to clarify what is being asked. Read [ask] and then provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce your problem, allowing us to better understand what is being asked.

Comment: @Forty3 If `.stringify` is not used, the controller method doesn't even fire.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
var model = {ID: EventID, 
        NewEventStart: EventStart, 
        NewEventEnd: EventEnd
        };
```

and then in your ajax post:

```
data: JSON.stringify(model),
```

It may not make any difference but I've never seen:

```
type: 'POST',
```

rather

```
type: "POST",
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am afraid it has had no effect.